# Character recognition using tesseract package in R

Tags: numbers, ocr, tesseract

I have images from trail cameras without any metadata. I have written code to use the tesseract package's ocr to recognize characters in the info bar of the images, but the ocr makes a lot of mistakes.

I have tried to follow the suggestions for improving the quality of my images prior to reading them with the ocr (suggestions for that [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md)), but have not been able to improve the accuracy of the ocr.

I've uploaded a folder with some sample images and an RProject with my code [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zfNKKlz3PJXNq-XX6QLnJ6rVnlAoGk4P?usp=sharing). I will also copy the R code below.

Does anyone have experience using tesseract in R and trying to recognize numbers and symbols? Any suggestions for how I could improve my approach? I have considered training tesseract but have not been able to use jTessBoxEditor correctly.

```
########## Read text from JPEG images and rename files
# Last modified by JYL on 13 July 2022
# Description: This code loads JPEG images from camera traps, crops them to just the info bar
# and reads the text from that cropped image into a dataframe. 

# clear the environment & set the seed
# This makes sure that all pertinent files are specified, and that the analysis is repeatable
remove(list = ls())
set.seed(2583722) # helps set a random-number so that what you do later is more reproducible


# Load libraries
library(tesseract)
library(magick)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

library(camtrapR)
library(exiftoolr)

# get set up
getwd()
wd_raw_images <- getwd()
camera <- 06
date = "06/18/2022"

# Read in the images
getwd()
allFiles = list.files(path = getwd(), 
                      pattern = ".jpg", full.names = TRUE,
                      recursive = FALSE)

# clear out any garbage (release some memory)
gc(full = TRUE)

# Get the dataframe with info
start_time <- Sys.time()
input <- magick::image_read(allFiles)
allInfo = image_info(input)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time

head(allInfo)
gc(full = TRUE)

# Attach the file names
allInfo$fileName = list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = ".jpg")
head(allInfo)

# Add row number as a column
allInfo <- allInfo %>% 
  mutate(row_id=row_number())
head(allInfo)

# Crop all images in the folder
# This will take R some time 

start_time <- Sys.time()
text2 <- input %>%
  image_crop("328x49+2332+1484") %>%
  image_quantize(colorspace = "gray") %>%
  image_negate()
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time 
text2[1]

gc(full = TRUE)

text2.2 <- text2 %>%
  image_scale("1640x245")
text2.2[1]

start_time <- Sys.time()
text2_2 <- text2.2 %>%
  image_transparent(color = "white", fuzz = 60) %>% 
  image_background("white") %>%
  image_threshold(type = "white", threshold = "50%") %>%
  image_threshold(type = "black", threshold = "50%")
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time 
text2_2[1]

gc(full = TRUE)

# Limit what characters tesseract sees
# Full list of tesseract parameters to play with: https://muthu.co/all-tesseract-ocr-options/

params <- tesseract_params("pageseg") #type in different words to find settings

# I've played with a lot of these settings, sometimes have to switch pageseg between 7 and 13
numbers <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_pageseg_mode = 13,
                                    tessedit_char_whitelist = ":0123456789APM",
                                    load_system_dawg = 0,
                                    load_freq_dawg = 0,
                                    #load_number_dawg = 0,
                                    #classify_bln_numeric_mode = 1,
                                    #rej_1Il_trust_permuter_type = 0,
                                    #max_permuter_attempts = 2,
                                    textord_space_size_is_variable = 0),
                     cache = TRUE) #changed to 0 for just time

# time_img_2 <- tesseract::ocr(time_img, engine = numbers)

start_time <- Sys.time()
text3 <- tesseract::ocr(text2_2, engine = numbers)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time 
text3[1:10]

# Turn tesseract output into a dataframe

text_1_df <- data.frame(text = read.delim(textConnection(text3),
                                          header = FALSE, 
                                          sep = "", 
                                          strip.white = TRUE))

start_time <- Sys.time()
text_1_df <- data.frame(text = read.delim(textConnection(text3),
                                          header = FALSE, 
                                          sep = "", 
                                          strip.white = TRUE))
text_1_df
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time

# Add row numbers as a column
text_1_df <- text_1_df %>% 
  mutate(row_id=row_number()) %>%
  rename(Time = V1) %>%
  add_column(Date = date)%>%
  add_column(Camera = camera) 
head(text_1_df)

text_1_df$Time <- gsub(".*2022","",as.character(text_1_df$Time))
head(text_1_df)

datetime <- tibble(text_1_df)
head(datetime)

# save the dataframe
write.csv(datetime, "UncleanImageData_JPG.csv", row.names = TRUE, quote = FALSE)
```